# How to cancel orders if they are not triggered within 1 bar?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How do i prevent orders from remaining open and executing later.

For long entries i have a buystop = high, so if the next candle the price doesn't hit the high it'll remain open until x number of candles print and finally price hits the valid candle high price.

Do we have the ability to only execute one bar after valid long/short entry?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are normally doing something like this:

```
long_cond = something

if (long_cond)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

You can then check if your condition was `true` one bar ago and if you are not in a long position at the moment.

```
is_long = strategy.position_size > 0
cancel_long_order = barstate.isconfirmed and long_cond[1] and not is_long

if (cancel_long_order)
    strategy.cancel("Long")
```

Comment: I'm also trying to do the same with entry 2 and 3. 
FYI: i have entry 2 only valid if entry 1 is open and entry 3 only if trade 1 and 2 are open.

Comment: edited comment from above: 

I'm also trying to do the same with entry 2 and 3. 
FYI: i have entry 2 only valid if entry 1 is open and entry 3 only if trade 1 and 2 are open by using strategy.opentrades == 1 (for long2) or 2(forlong2)

How would "cancel_long_order" look like if "is_long" would be true in the case of trade 2 and 3 since they are only executed if position size > 0